Lemma 4.2B of Humphreys's Lie Algebras and Representation Theory.
I'm having trouble understanding the proof of this lemma. I attach the statement of the lemma and the proof that Humphrey's gives.
LEMMA B
I understand how $\mathfrak{A}$ decomposes as the direct sum of the $\mathfrak{A_a}$'s (according to me this is due to the usual decomposition of generalized eigenspaces). What I don't understand is the following: $\sigma$ acts on $\mathfrak{A}_a$ as a scalar multiplication by $a$.
With this the proof becomes simple knowing that $\mathfrak{A}_a \mathfrak{A}_b \subseteq \mathfrak{A}_{a+b}$. According to me, what should be proven, according to what the book says, is that $\sigma(x)=ax$ for all $x\in \mathfrak{A}_{a}$, but I have not been able to prove it (I think it is not even true). For example, if we consider $V_a$ the generalized eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue $a$ (of $\sigma$), then there we would have to $(\sigma - a1) |_{V_a} = 0$. But sets $\mathfrak{A}_{a}$ and $V_a$ are not equal, I only know that $V_{a} \subseteq \mathfrak{A}_{a}$. If you could help me understand the proof I would be very grateful.

Actually, we only attach pictures to upload the geometry picture. Otherwise, for equations, we better use MathJax(or Latex) to type it out.

In the book $\delta = \sigma + \nu$, where $\sigma \in End(\mathfrak{A})$ is the semisimple part of $\delta$, and $\nu \in End(\mathfrak{A})$ is the nilpotent part of $\delta$.
So on $\mathfrak{A}_a = \{ x \in End(\mathfrak{A}) : (\delta- a\cdot 1)^k x = 0 \text{ for some } k\}$, the action of $\delta$ on $\mathfrak{A}_a$ is a direct sum of Jordan blocks of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} a & 1 & \\  & a & 1 \\ & & \ddots & 1 \\ & & & a \end{pmatrix}$$
Then the action of $\sigma$ is by scalar multiplication with $a$, and $\nu$ is a direct sum of the nilpotent Jordan blocks $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & \\  & 0 & 1 \\ & & \ddots & 1 \\ & & & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
This is explained in the beginning of Section 4.2 in the book by Humphreys.

That action is on a particular basis, right?

@Juan: Yes, of course. It's just the Jordan normal form.
